# My custom component cannot be painted

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to create a class(called Stock) which can be identified as a Component--and let me use Listener on it.
However, it is not painted unless you specify (not a good idea!) to paint it in panel.paint().
The program runs as this:

```
          JFrame frame = new JFrame ("..");
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          final Stock theStock=new Stock();
          JPanel primary = new JPanel();
          primary.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
          primary.add(theStock);
          frame.getContentPane().add(primary);
          frame.pack();
          frame.setVisible(true);
```

The Stock will not be painted unless primary(JPanel) is overriden so that there is a specification calling the stock to draw:

```
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(x-2, y-2, 74, 124);
    }
```

Here's my code--I guess the problem may happen because I did not override anything else than paint method inherited from Component.

**********Modified to be testable, please see below
**

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Stock extends Component{
    private int x; //the position for image
    private int y;//position for image

    public Stock() {
        x=285;
        y=280;

    }


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(x-2, y-2, 74, 124);
    }

    public void works(){
          JFrame frame = new JFrame ("..");
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          final Stock theStock=new Stock();
          JPanel primary = new JPanel(){
                @Override
                protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                    super.paintComponent(g);
                    theStock.paint(g);
                }
          };
          primary.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
          primary.add(theStock);
          frame.getContentPane().add(primary);
          frame.pack();
          frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void doesNotWork(){
          JFrame frame = new JFrame ("..");
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          final Stock theStock=new Stock();
          JPanel primary = new JPanel();
          primary.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
          primary.add(theStock);
          frame.getContentPane().add(primary);
          frame.pack();
          frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stock a = new Stock();
        a.works();
        //a.doesNotWork();
    }
}
```

p.s.1. I'm not using JComponent because JComponent has more functionalities than I need to use. Component, as from which Container and Button inherit, should work well.

p.s.2. Even you use JComponent you get the same result. Code below.

```
    import java.awt.*;
```

import javax.swing.*;

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Stock extends JComponent{
    private int x; //the position for image
    private int y;//position for image

    public Stock() {
        x=285;
        y=280;

    }



    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(x-2, y-2, 74, 124);
    }

    public void works(){
          JFrame frame = new JFrame ("..");
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          final Stock theStock=new Stock();
          JPanel primary = new JPanel(){
                @Override
                protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                    super.paintComponent(g);
                    theStock.paint(g);
                }
          };
          primary.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
          primary.add(theStock);
          frame.getContentPane().add(primary);
          frame.pack();
          frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void doesNotWork(){
          JFrame frame = new JFrame ("..");
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          final Stock theStock=new Stock();
          JPanel primary = new JPanel();
          primary.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
          primary.add(theStock);
          frame.getContentPane().add(primary);
          frame.pack();
          frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stock a = new Stock();
        //a.works();
        a.doesNotWork();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your main method? How are you using this class? And @Ashiquzzaman, he can't override paintComponent because his class (for some unknown reason) does not extend JComponent or JPanel but rather the AWT class Component?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, Sorry I had not noticed.

Comment: @Ashiquzzaman: no problem, but the other issues in my post above remain. Mr. K. Mole -- please show us how you use this class, and please tell us why you're trying to use the out-of-date AWT component class, Component and not the less out-of-date Swing component classes.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels A question about AWT components has nothing to do with the `main` method, and not much to do with how the component is being used (since components are generally self-contained).

Comment: @K.Mole Is this component at least 300x300 pixels or so? If it's smaller than that, the rectangle will be off the side of the component, and you won't see it.

Comment: @immibis: perhaps you're right, main is the wrong way to state it, but context is important, including where the component is and how large it is, what it is added to. The best "why isn't this code working" type questions have [mcve] that do have main methods, so that we can run, modify and test the program to find out what's wrong. So I definitely want more context in any shape and form, preferably the [mcve].

Comment: My fear is that he's creating a CopyOfStock object, but is not adding it to anything.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I instantiated this class in another Panel (this.add(myStock). I posted this CopyOfStock just to make the question more obvious (I hope), that the bug should locate somewhere in my understanding of customizing a component class.<br>I'm going to modify the question ;)

Comment: *"I'm going to modify the question"*  When you do, please be sure to include a [mcve] rather than text descriptions of the missing code..

Comment: Please read the link provided by @HovercraftFullOfEels!  3 code snippets do not 'add up' to one MCVE..

Comment: BTW - this custom component would be assigned a size of 0x0 in a flow layout..

Comment: @immibis hi,immibis,plz see my program (updated just now)

Comment: @AndrewThompson updated. I was being lazy so did not delete all unnecessary codes and copied and pasted from different programs I was using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is one of layouts, size and preferredSize. Since you're adding a your Stock Component to a FlowLayout using JPanel, the Component will size itself at its preferred size which is 0, 0. If you gave the JPanel a different layout, say

```
      primary.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

and then added your Stock object, it would fill the primary JPanel and it would paint itself.

Other options include setting your Stock objects preferredSize, or even overriding its `getPreferredSize()` method so that it's large enough:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
        return super.getPreferredSize();
    }
    return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
}
```